# Randomise Geometry Node Input Value

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am learning Geometry Nodes. I have created a simple scene where trees are randomly distributed on a grid. The trees change in appearance as they scale on the z-axis. All of this is controlled by an input value. How can I create random scaled instances of my trees by randomizing the input value. I probably have my nodes in the wrong order as it looks like I am distributing the same instance with the same scale on my grid.

Sorry. I am trying to attach my blend file using Blend-Exchange but it keeps telling me that "All uploaded files must be in the blend file format". I have only added my file Geom_Trees.blend???

Here is my node setup:
[image: Geom_Trees Node Setup]

Current result:
[image: Geom_Trees Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. As I expected, it was just my node order.

[image]
[image]